# How to download JAR from Maven and add to non-Maven IntelliJ WAR project

Tags: intellij-idea, web-applications, jar

I need to setup https://github.com/adminfaces but i can't make it work at all. I get errors in wildfly deployment.

I setup intellij project, i select framework support for JSF, and Primefaces which are prerequisites. But than docs say:

**Add admin theme to your classpath:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.adminfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin-theme</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RC9</version>
</dependency>
```

How do i do this if i don't use maven? Can i set it up, via some jar file. Also i don't get it, if i download release from github, what is install.sh?

But even if i added it through maven via Intellij browser it still doesn't work. Can't deploy to Wildfly.

Comment: How is AdminFaces related to PrimeFaces? I don't see anything PrimeFaces related here.

Comment: From the docs: **"AdminFaces is an open source project which brings Bootstrap and AdminLTE to your application via a PrimeFaces theme and a JSF responsive template."** I written it, Primefaces is prerequisite.

Comment: Sure, but so is a jdk, servlet container, operatingsystem, cpu, elektricity, life... That does not mean it is jsf or PrimeFaces related. Effectively your question is: "How can I use a jar in my project if I don't use maven"

Comment: And why did you pick out the Primefaces as the main issue here? Who said that? And why the Primefaces bug you out? There is no jar file for the adminfaces(i can't find it anyway), so i asked if someone worked with this already to help me get going. So no question is not essentially how to add jar file to project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You have placed tag [primefaces] on question but this isn't a PrimeFaces problem. Kukeltje is simply following [primefaces] tag to find interesting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven library can be added to non Maven project through Intellij IDEA.

Project structure->Libraries->Add library->From Maven[image]

Answer (score 0):

AdminFaces jars are published to maven central, you can download it there, [see here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.adminfaces%22%20AND%20p%3A%22jar%22).

Just add admin-template and admin-theme to your classpath.

Also it depends on [OmniFaces](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22omnifaces%22%20AND%20p%3A%22jar%22) (2.x) and [PrimeFaces](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22primefaces%22%20AND%20p%3A%22jar%22) (5.1.1 or greater) and also JavaEE apis such as servlet, EJB, CDI, JSF and JPA.

If you are running it outside a JavaEE container such as Tomcat take a look at [Admin Starter Tomcat dependencies](https://github.com/adminfaces/admin-starter-tomcat/blob/master/pom.xml), you should be able to download them from maven central as well.

Comment: Do i need both admin-template and admin-theme? I think docs say only admin-theme is enough.

Comment: If you are only interested on the theme and not the template then yes, only the theme is enough.

Comment: rmpestano I've downloaded jars from maven central, added as libraries in netbeans project, yet resourses from template are not loaded. Only plain text is displayed and requests for defined properties. For instance 404 page is rendered like this: ```#{adm['label.404.header']}
#{adm['label.404.message']}.

#{adm['label.go-back']} . ```

Comment: " For instance 404 page is rendered like this: #{adm['label.404.header']} #{adm['label.404.message']}. #{adm['label.go-back']}"

This usually happens when you have a different `url-pattern` for FacesServlet then the default one (`*.xhtml`). In this case you need to redefine error pages location to match your pattern, see an [example here](https://github.com/adminfaces/admin-starter/blob/fc197cee164435b46208428f7b737f07f16035da/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L67-L100) .